# ,JDK / JRE integration in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for Java Developers (Keppler) and JDK 8.

While using some Java-7 features like `int i = 1_2_3;`Eclipse would complain that `Java Compliance Level` is set to `1.4`. So after browsing through some Stackoverflow threads I would would set it to 1.7 and then after installing the Updates as mentioned [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/) to 1.8.

But I still wonder **how** does Eclipse use the JDK/JRE or **what parts** of it does it use to be precise?

And what exactly is the `Compliance level`?

How can I control the use of Java by Eclipse like when I want to use specific libraries or switch versions between projects?

Would someone be so kind to provide me with some basic knowledge so that I can understand what this is all about?

Answer (score 1):

The *Compliance level* is set globally in the workspace, however you can override this at project level, in the *Java Compiler* pane of the *Preferences*. It basically sets the version of the generated Java classes, and the Java version you can program against.